# unable to validate the checkboxs in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I am new to JavaScript. My need is to validate the checkbox form. I can able to validate single checkbox but unable to validate multiple checkbox value.

```js
function validate(form) {
  if (form.answer.checked == false) {
    alert('select anwser!'); //able to validate
    return false;
  }

  if (form.answers.checked == false) {
    alert('You must choose any anwsers!'); //unable to validate
    return false;
  }
}
```

```html
<form id="surveyform" action="#" onsubmit="return validate(this)">
  <input type="checkbox" name="answer" value="answer1" />answer
  <br><br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="answers[]" value="answer1" />answer1
  <input type="checkbox" name="answers[]" value="answer2" />answer2
  <input type="checkbox" name="answers[]" value="answer3" />answer3
  <input type="checkbox" name="answers[]" value="answer4" />answer4
  <br><br>
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try looping through the answers array and check for true in each checkboxes, for that you can use forEach to loop through them.